# Display table values vertically while keeping table structure

Tags: php, transpose

Been checking out other ways used to order array values **vertically** for use in a table but most of them were the equivalent of flipping your table 90 deg to the right. I've been trying to think of a way to properly implement this but I think I need some help.

For example, the table (horizontal order):

```
a  b  c  d  e
f  g  h  i  j
k  l  m  n  o
p  q  r
```

Is reordered to (vertical order):

```
a  e  i  m  p
b  f  j  n  q
c  g  k  o  r
d  h  l
```

As you can see the structure is retained since the last 2 cells are empty.

Not like this:

```
a  e  i  m  q
b  f  j  n  r
c  g  k  o
d  h  l  p
```

In this example, the table is akin to flipping it sideways. Does anyone know how to properly do this?

Comment: Do you want to render table values from the database?

Comment: Yup, but you can keep it simple and use an array for this example: `array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED: This is harder than I thought and I messed it up the first time (or two).  It should work now.

Let's say you have your table structure stored in a two dimensional array:

```
$data = array(
  array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
  array('f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'),
  array('k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'),
  array('p', 'q', 'r')
);
```

Since you want to keep the same "shape" you need to determine the dimensions of the table.  To do this we can take the `count` of the first row, since we know that the first row must be the maximum width of the table.  The height is just the number of elements in the array.

```
$width = count($data[0]); // 5
$height = count($data);   // 4
```

We also need the total number of elements, but we can overestimate by taking $width * $height.

```
$total = $width * $height; // 20
```

Then it's really just a little math to calculate where things go.  We have to use a separate counter for the old and new indices because we will have to increment them differently once we start to have holes.

```
$new_data = array();
$j = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
  $old_x = floor($i / $width); // integer division
  $old_y = $i % $width;        // modulo

  do {
    $new_x = $j % $height;        // modulo
    $new_y = floor($j / $height); // integer division
    $j++;
  // move on to the next position if we have reached an index that isn't available in the old data structure
  } while (!isset($data[$new_x][$new_y]) && $j < $total);

  if (!isset($new_data[$new_x])) {
    $new_data[$new_x] = array();
  }
  if (isset($data[$old_x][$old_y])) {
    $new_data[$new_x][$new_y] = $data[$old_x][$old_y];
  }
}
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't test it before I posted it the first time and I switched the width and height around.  The post is fixed now.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. Your first row came out as `a e i m q` when it should be `a e i m p`. Since the first row is wrong then the rest of the rows moved as well. Also, rows 1-3 need to have 5 columns while in your example only rows 1-2 have 5 elements.

Comment: Okay I thought about this more and updated the answer.  It should work now.

Comment: The answer is still `O(n^2)` as you are looping through the total which is the width * height

Comment: Sorry, I was never good in math but what's the `O` in `O(n^2)` and how does it fit this solution?

Comment: You are completely right @Andy.  I confused myself here.  The O is "big O notation": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation.  This thread has a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to subtract one for the "hanging" columns. That is the columns that have a value missing in the last row.

```
// setup some initial test data... rip this out and replace with whatever
$values = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < 18; ++$x)
  $values[] = chr($x + ord("a"));
```

We can arbitrarily change the number of columns. The number of rows is determines by the size of our data divided by the number of columns we use.

```
// change # of columns to desired value
$columns = 5;
$rows = (int) ceil(count($values) / $columns);
```

Some columns hang. That is the column is missing a value in the last row.

```
// the number of columns that will "hang" or miss a value in the last row
$hanging_columns = $columns * $rows - count($values);

$counter = 0;
for ($y = 0; $y < $rows; ++$y) {
  for ($x = 0; $x < $columns; ++$x) {
    // if we've displayed all values, stop
    if ($counter++ >= count($values)) break;

    // calculate the correct index to display
    $index = ($y + $x * $rows);
    // if we are in a hanging column, we need to back up by one
    if ($x > $columns - $hanging_columns) $index -= 1;

    // display the value
    echo $values[$index] . " ";
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution

```
$unflipped = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 
               'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
               'k', 'l', 'm', 'n');


function flip90($arr, $lineHeight) 
{
    $tbl = array();

    $index = 0;
    $counter = 1;


    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
    {
        if($counter > $lineHeight)
        {
            $index++;
            $counter = 1;
        }

        if($counter <= $lineHeight) 
        {
            $tbl[$index][$counter] = $arr[$i];

            $counter++;
        }

    }

    return $tbl;
}

$flipped = flip90($unflipped, 5);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($flipped);
echo "<pre>";
```

The function needs the array and the line height for dimensioning your table